# How to remove text after certain word

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a string

```
The best laid schemes of mice and men
```

How do I remove all text after the word "schemes" in ColdFusion? I suppose this can be done with regex.

Comment: Not an answer - but good answers have been given already anyhow - but for future referemce, it's perhaps worth pointing out CF's regex implementation is well documented: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html

Answer (score 10):

Here ya go:

```
<cfset myString = "The best laid schemes of mice and men" />
<cfoutput>#REReplace(myString, "schemes(.*)", "schemes")#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I'm gonna -1 you here Dan, because @Stema's answer is better IMO: there's no gain in capturing the subexpression here, so there's no point in doing it.

Comment: That makes sense, and you're right, though `REReplace` doesn't return anything other than the modified string anyway. I wonder what the performance implications may be? Should I update my answer to take the other RegEx into account, or just leave it as is?

Comment: There will be a slight overhead as the regex engine needs to remember what the subexpression was (so: it needs to store it somewhere).  This won't be an issue if the string is short, but could be a consideration if the subexpression ends up being big.   That said, I have never analysed what any performance degradation might be from this.  Don't forget if you ever NEED to group something, you can use (?:) to work the same as (), except it doesn't remember what was within the parentheses.  I'd leave your example as is, because it's a good discussion point, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is:

```
schemes.*$
```

and replace with "schemes"

**Explanation**

`.*$` means match any character (`.`) 0 or more times (`*`) till the end of the row (`$`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
schemes(.*)
```

Replace $1 with empty string ""